# Let $\mathcal C^{n}([a,b])$ be a space of functions on the interval

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\mathcal C^{n}([a,b])$ be a space of functions on the interval $[a,b]$with the property that all derivatives up to n are continuous.
Define norm in which convergence of a sequence $(f_k)$ will be an uniform convergence for itself and for its all derivatives up to n.

As I recall metric defined as $d(f_k,f) = \sup_{t\in [a,b]}|f_k(t)-f(t)|$ is an uniform convergence metric. But what should we do with these n derivatives. 
Is the norm $\Vert f \Vert = \sum_{i=0}^n(\sup_{t\in [a,b]}|f^{(i)}(t)|)$
an answer for that?

Comment: Seems like a good idea.  All you need to show is that $\Vert f_k - f \Vert \to 0$ when $(f_k)$ converges to $f$ uniformly along with its first $n$ derivatives.

Comment: Yes. Convergence of a sequence of functions $\{ f_k \}$ in your norm is then equivalent to uniform convergence of $\{ f_k \}_{k=1}^{\infty}, \{f_k^{(1)}\}_{k=1}^{\infty},\cdots,\{ f_k^{(n)} \}_{k=1}^{\infty}$

Comment: How do we show that for every k = 1,2,3,.., n, the sequence of derivatives is also uniform convergent?